# How to get the headers in the grid aligned with the body?

Tags: css

I have the following html and css. I want to achieve a dynamic number of columns on the below table. But the headers in the grid are not same width as the other rows' columns. any idea? thanks!

```css
table.list {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-auto-columns: minmax(200px, max-content);
}

thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

th {
  padding: 4px;
}

tbody {
  overflow: auto;
}

tr {
  line-height: 1.5;
  border: none;
  border-collapse: none;
  min-height: 40px;
}

tr:nth-child(2n) td {
  background-color: red;
}

tr:hover td {
  background-color: pink;
}

td {
  min-height: 40px;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class="list" role="grid">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th role="columnheader">Date</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Action</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Comment</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Text</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="gridcell">Mar 20</td>
      <td role="gridcell">Some action</td>
      <td role="gridcell">asdasdsadasdsa</td>
      <td role="gridcell">Some more text </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="gridcell">Mar 14</td>
      <td role="gridcell">Some action</td>
      <td role="gridcell">asdasdsadsadsadsa</td>
      <td role="gridcell">Some more text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I've not seen people combining HTML tables and CSS grid before, that feels like two different ways to achieve similar results.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to  use CSS grid ? Using HTML tables and CSS grid seems a bit redondant for me.

If not, just simply remove `display: grid;` from `table.list` in your CSS and it will solve the issue.

```css
table.list {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-auto-columns: minmax(200px, max-content);
}

thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

th {
  padding: 4px;
}

tbody {
  overflow: auto;
}

tr {
  line-height: 1.5;
  border: none;
  border-collapse: none;
  min-height: 40px;
}

tr:nth-child(2n) td {
  background-color: red;
}

tr:hover td {
  background-color: pink;
}

td {
  min-height: 40px;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class="list" role="grid">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th role="columnheader">Date</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Action</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Comment</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Text</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="gridcell">Mar 20</td>
      <td role="gridcell">Some action</td>
      <td role="gridcell">asdasdsadasdsa</td>
      <td role="gridcell">Some more text </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="gridcell">Mar 14</td>
      <td role="gridcell">Some action</td>
      <td role="gridcell">asdasdsadsadsadsa</td>
      <td role="gridcell">Some more text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: hi fifi, yes you are right. But, how can I make the width of the tablecells adjust according to the content?

Comment: never mind, i figured it out with min-width :) Dont know what i was thinking!